# Duplicating table rows when using SqlDataAdapter.Update Method

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, datatable, duplicates

In my project I have table "Product".

```
ID  Name   Price
------------------  
1   xyz     100

2   abc     200

3   pqr     300
```

In my c# code I would like to update my table rows using SqlAdapter.
For that i crated a datatable

```
DataTable dtTable=new DataTable("Product");
```

Add updated values to Datatable .That is,

```
ID  Name   Price
    ------------------  
    1   aaa     100

    2   bbb     200

    3   ccc     300
```

I used the following step to update table in database with this values

```
SqlConnection myLocalConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + dtTable.TableName, myLocalConnection);
 SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);

     mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dtTable);
```

But when executing this update function, In database all tables are duplicated.
that is

```
ID  Name   Price
------------------  
1   xyz     100

2   abc     200

3   pqr     300

4   aaa     100

5   bbb     200

6   ccc     300
```

I only want to replace the existing data. Why these rows are duplicated in this table.
Please help

Comment: you need to initialize `dtTable` to get new values

Answer (score 0):

According to [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx) you have to specify your update command by yourself and then you can call the Update function of the sql data adapter!

```
SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = 
     new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + dtTable.TableName, myLocalConnection);
dataAdpater.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ...", connection);
mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dtTable);
```